# Disable messages from Log4J

Tags: java, log4j2, log4j

I have this example of Log4J configuration.

```
Logger log = Logger.getRootLogger();
        BasicConfigurator.configure();  // Basic configuration for Log4J 1.x

        ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
        //configure the appender
        console.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n"));
        console.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        console.activateOptions();
        //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);
```

Into the console I get this output:

```
0 [FelixStartLevel] INFO root  - test____scs
26/12/2013 14:15:10 test____scs
```

This message `0 [FelixStartLevel] INFO root  - test____scs` is printed by the code `Logger log = Logger.getRootLogger();` How i can disable this code?

Comment: simply comment this line

 Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);

Comment: Yes but I want to print the messages `26/12/2013 14:15:10 test____scs `

Comment: comment this line console.activateOptions();

and run it see the output.

Comment: I get this `0 [FelixStartLevel] INFO root  - test____scs
log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [null].`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CLASSNAME.class);

logger.info("WRITE YOUR MESSAGE"):
```

Comment: I get this message: `0 [FelixStartLevel] INFO org.DX_57.osgi.ts.impl.LogMessages  - test____scs
26/12/2013 14:39:04 test____scs
Tracking Service started` I want only to get this: `26/12/2013 14:15:10 test____scs`

Comment: in info method pass you date object.
logger.info(new Date()+"test___scs");

Comment: The question is how I can prevent this `0 [FelixStartLevel] INFO root - test____scs` from printing?

Comment: i don't know from its coming. my answer isn't working?

Comment: Maybe I have to remove `BasicConfigurator.configure();`?

Comment: Yes, this causes the problem.